# Updated zurb-foundation gem from 4.2.3 to 4.3.1 - Orbit no longer works

Tags: rubygems, zurb-foundation, orbit

I Updated the zurb-foundation gem from 4.2.3 to 4.3.1 - Orbit no longer works.

The dots show up and cycle, but no images are displayed.

I need to either get the new version working, or revert to the previous version that worked.

```
        <div id="featured"><ul data-orbit>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500&text=Slide Image 1" alt="slide image">
        <div class="orbit-caption">Caption 1</div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500&text=Slide Image 2" alt="slide image"> 
         <div class="orbit-caption">Caption 2</div>
          </li>
          <li><img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500&text=Slide Image 3" alt="slide image">
         <div class="orbit-caption">Caption 3</div>
          </li>
        </ul></div>
```

is the html code. I'm using the default css styling and linking to foundation.min.js.
If I change the link to foundation.js, then it doesn't work at all and I see a ginormous list.

Please help - I'm on a deadline and have wasted a couple of days on this.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem when I updated Foundation in my gemfile. I was getting errors with Abide and Orbit. Turns out that they changed a few things in the "foundation_and_overrides.scss" file that were causing strange unintended issues.

My fix was to simply copy out the changes I had made to that file and then just run the install again for foundation.

```
rails g foundation:install
```

I didn't want it to overwrite any of my files, so when it asked, I simply told it to skip them.

Hope this helps someone! It was a very frustrating issue and I was unable to receive any help from Zurb on the matter.

Comment: where did you find the foundation_and_overrides.scss file   I'm not using rails.  I just tripped over this again.  My solution was to uninstall the update, but I'd really like to know what happened.

Comment: I would assume it would be located with your other Stylesheets, or in the folder where you have Foundation installed. Without more information about your configuration i'm not sure how much help I can be. Also if they answer was at all helpful I'd appreciate and upvote and to be selected as answer :D

Comment: I'm not using rails and never did find that file anywhere.  I realized I'd have to bit the bullet and install bundler to manage different versions.  But thanks anyway.